# What is the correct way to upgrade Realm database library version on Android?

Tags: android, realm

We currently use Realm 6.x.
However when trying to update the library to the latest version (10.x), the app crashes during opening opening.

In the app, realm is currently configured to delete all data on schema change and compact db on open. But even with this setting the app crashes.

Is this normal that major version update causes crash?

What’s the proper way to upgrade? Is it possible to do it without loosing data?

Answer (score 0):

Alright for realm database follow this approach.

```java
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .schemaVersion(2) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
    .migration(new MyMigration()) // Migration to run
    .build();

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

// This will automatically trigger the migration if needed
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

```java
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        // Migrate from version 0 to version 1
        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmObjectSchema userSchema = schema.get("User");

            userSchema.addField("testRealm", String.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }

        if (oldVersion == 1) { // ...
            // ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return MyMigration.class.hashCode(); }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) { return object != null && object instanceof MyMigration; }
}
```

Also consider that
**Realm.init(this)** sets a default *RealmConfiguration* and should `ONLY` be called inside `Application.onCreate`

Comment: Realm should automatically handle adding fields provided you just increment the schema version number. Migration code only explicitly needed for converting data types or inserting new default data.